# How to pass fetch data from DB to all views except admin in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I want to send data from database to my front end header menu for category listing. But I don't want to send these data to my Admin views as these are irrelevant. Should I use Service Providers or any better approach?

Comment: You should add some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following within the boot method of the `AppServiceProvider`:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    if(Auth::user()->is_admin == false) {
        $view->with('menuCategories', Category::all());
    }
});
```

The `*` means all views will receive `$menuCategories`.

Later on you can extract it to a dedicated `ServicePovider`.

Comment: `$view` is not triggered if you are an admin.

Comment: Okay..now I got it..Thank you

Comment: Ok, one more thing, use `$menuCategories` in a subview, and use the name of the subview instead of `*`. Otherwise the query is triggered once for every view included.